# Extract URLs from paragraph or block of text using a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text and a script

```js
var x = "This is an example url http://www.longurl.com/?a=example@gmail.com&x=y1 and this must me a example url";

function getMatch(str) {
  var urlRegex = '(?!mailto:)(?:(?:http|https|ftp)://)(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[0-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,})))|localhost)(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:(/|\\?|#)[^\\s]*)?';
  var reg = new RegExp(urlRegex, 'ig');
  return str.match(reg);
}

console.log(getMatch(x));
```

The expected outcome must be

```
[ http://www.longurl.com/?a=example@gmail.com&x=y1 ]
```

but the below getMatch is giving me incorrectly (skipping &x=y1)

```
http://www.longurl.com/?a=example@gmail.com
```

How do I modify the function to return a complete URL

> NOTE: This happens only when the email arguments are passed after it
> finds @ character, the function behaves weird.

Comment: I think this should do `/https?:\/\/(www\.)?[A-Za-z]+\.\S+/gi`

Comment: How to match a ftp, mailto, https

Comment: It already matches both "http" and "https"; if you need to include "ftp" and "mailto" URLs then you can do `/(mailto|ftp|https?):\/\/\S+/gi`; this would match everything from the protocol up to the first space (not included).

Comment: Note that if you have a URL such as `mailto://name.surname@domain.tld?subject='email subject'` (notice the space between "email" and "subject"), the above RegExp would match only `mailto://name.surname@domain.tld?subject='email`; if you can have URLs containing a space, you need something more refined.

Comment: ... and, now that I think about it, the "mailto:" protocol does not have forward-slashes, so the RegExp should be: `/(mailto:|ftp:\/\/|https?:\/\/)\S+/gi`, apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simplify:

```js
var x = `This is an example url http://www.longurl.com/?a=example@gmail.com&x=y1 and this must me a example url

http://            www.longurl.com/?a=example@gmail.com&x=y1 (with an arbitrary number of spaces between the protocol and the beginning of the url) 
here is a mailto:a@b.c?subject=aaa%20bbb and some more text
So https://www.google.com/search?q=bla or ftp://aaa:bbb@server.com could appear`

function getMatch(str) {
  var urlRegex = /((mailto:|ftp:\/\/|https?:\/\/)\S+?)[^\s]+/ig;
  return str.match(urlRegex);
}

console.log(getMatch(x));
```

Comment: That RegExp would match also `http://            www.longurl.com/?a=example@gmail.com&x=y1` (with an arbitrary number of spaces between the protocol and the beginning of the url)

Comment: Thanks, then I just steal [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65939420/extract-urls-from-paragraph-or-block-of-text-using-a-regular-expression/65939778?noredirect=1#comment116586292_65939420) ;)

Comment: be my guest... but take care to include also the last amendment about "mailto:" protocol, which is not followed by "//" ;)

Comment: @secan Maybe you just post YOUR answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Supposing an URL always start with `http` and can not have an empty space, a solution would be:

`http[^ ]+`

`[^ ]+` will match one or more non white-space characters.

Comment: Its not expected answer. How do I modify the regex to match the entire URL

Comment: Depends on what exactly are you expecting. The accepted answer would not match `https://   www.   google.com`; however the formulated question *does not* make clear whether it should be accepted. In short: maybe a better description on whatever you expected to be the answer would help.